# java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"

Tags: java

I have two cases

1. Input-> 3,4,1

Get last value into a vector. so Vector cls contains 1.
So for further processing I am converting it to integer

```
int c = Integer.parseInt(cls.get(0));
```

this works fine
But for 2 nd case it fails.

2. 3.0,4.0,1.0

Vector cls contains 1.0
and while converting to int it fails with NumberFormatException

```
int c= Integer.parseInt(cls.get(0));
```

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"
>     at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

What can I do as a workaround by keeping Vector as String itself.
Edit
I need to work my code for both the cases.

Comment: an Integer is not a decimal type. When you have decimals, try with Double or Float instead.

Comment: its a double so you have to use  double d = Double.parseDouble(cls.get(0));
int i = (int) d;

Comment: How can I work for both cases?

Comment: catch and try again for double/float...

Answer (score 8):

```
int c=(int)Double.parseDouble(cls.get(0));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int c = 0;

try {

    c = Integer.parseInt(cls.get(0));

} catch(NumberFormatException e) {

    double d = Double.parseDouble(cls.get(0)); 

    c = (int) d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use type float, like `float c = Float.parseFloat(cls.get(0));`